# Completely unable to use the Steam client

Tags: steam, windows-7

I am on 64-bit Windows 7 Professional.

I am unable to use the Steam client at all. The problem began when I loaded Steam today and went to my Library tab--it caused the client to crash. I do not have any custom games installed; only Skyrim which was purchased and downloaded through Steam. I had not done anything to cause this, it just crashed.

Following the crash, I reopened the client and continued to download the game I was downloading at the time (PlanetSide 2), only to find that it now would not download no matter what I did. I tried changing my download region and deleting ClientRegistry.blob, but its status stayed at `Updating...`. I decided to just uninstall Steam and retry from scratch.

After Steam uninstalled, I restarted my computer, then reinstalled it. Now when I try to open Steam it continuously opens, downloads an 8,691 KB update, says `Extracting package...` for several seconds, then completely closes.

- VPN is turned off
- All Steam ports are open through my router
- Tried removing ClientRegistry.blob
- Completely uninstalled antivirus and MalwareBytes
- Tried uninstalling/reinstalling Steam using [these instructions](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=9609-OBMP-2526), didn't fix it

I have been trying to get this to work for a full hour and a half now, and I cannot get anything to work no matter what I try. Any advice at all would be incredibly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried contacting Steam Support?

Answer (score 8):

I have now discovered the issue (after posting, of course). I have a Ralink RT2860 wireless card that I use to connect to the internet, and the newest (albeit three years old) drivers [apparently cause the issue](http://steamcommunity.com/discussions/forum/1/864961537279691807/).

If anyone else has this issue, you can download the working drivers (version 3.0.11) from [this link](http://wikidrivers.com/wiki/Ralink_RT2860_3.0.11.0/2.3.11.0/1.4.12.0).